# Issue with getting result by database where session id is logged in user id and I would have to check uid which i am getting by link

Tags: php, mysql

```
$getwhole_messages = $db->query("
SELECT * FROM `user_messages` 
WHERE `sender_id`='".$_SESSION['RVuser']."' ||
`reciever_id`='".$_SESSION['RVuser']."' &&
`sender_id`='".$_GET['uid']."' ||
`reciever_id`='".$_GET['uid']."'"
);
```

Where as I want to put check that will let me know that session id is match with uid. It would be in sender_id or reciever_id.

Comment: Is your query working? To me it seems there are illegal keywords in your query, but my MySQL is a bit rusty. You should also provide more context as of now your question is very vague.

Comment: No my query is not working.

Comment: I want to fetch data from database where sender_id = 1 OR reciever_id = 1 where sender_id = 2 or sender_id = 2

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Whenever possible use prepared statements and placeholders to ensure you're not exposed to errors of that sort. If this is PDO, you really have no excuse for not using the [prepared statements feature](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, beyond what tadman said (You're at severe risk of SQL injection attacks), this query is left way too open.

You have this matching when any of these conditions exist:

**Condition 1:** When sender_id = $_SESSION['RVuser']

**Condition 2:** When receiver_id = $_SESSION['RVuser'] AND sender_id = $_GET['uid']

**Condition 3:** When receiver_id = $_GET['uid']

So all it would take is for someone to load your page with `?uid=#` to get information because of condition 3.

Answer (score -1):

Always sanitize vulnerable inputs! I'm assuming you're using MySQLi in my example.

```
$select = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user_messages WHERE sender_id=%d || reciever_id=%d && sender_id=%d || reciever_id=%d;",
  $_SESSION['RVuser'],
  $_SESSION['RVuser'],
  $db->real_escape_string($_GET['uid']),
  $db->real_escape_string($_GET['uid'])
);

if($getwhole_messages = $db->query($select))
  // Prosess results
} else {
  // Output Query error
}
```

Please provide error details so we can provide more of an answer.

Comment: What the heck is `sprintf` doing here? That's not how you do it. Just use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) like you're supposed to.

Comment: real_escape_string should be unnecessary with %d (integer) but you're making the assumption these are integers.

Comment: @tadman I would have suggested that if OP was setting up a prepared statement. I used code that was similar to what he was already using.

Comment: @Devon I would agree, it's just a matter of habit for me to escape any input that could be vulnerable.

Comment: Look I want to get the record just in between the user logged In and the url get id user with my query it show me the same record on all url get id's i just need to separate them like who send the message and to who recieve it.

Comment: @HassanAli You can't just slap together some code and throw it on the internet. Your code is so full of holes someone could hijack your server and do whatever they wanted. Please, use `bind_param`. It's not hard and it it *will* properly escape things, meaning you spend no time tracking down missing or duplicated quotes.

Comment: @Twisty, real_escape_string is outdated in my opinion,  it is best to recommend prepared statements if you use strings.  This would be fine if you're forcing integers but prepared statements can also perform better so it makes sense to use them in almost all situations.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your suggestion. I will use this bind_param. will it solve the issue the main thing is what query should it be to get the record from the database.

Comment: @HassanAli, take a look at my answer (long comment).  I assume this is not the functionality you want, you have it set up so anyone can get a user's messages if they know their uid.

Comment: ok good i will try it. if i do put check on uid that the loggedin user is added as a friend with uid or not so will it be helpful and stop to get track down?